# Send document from document library as an attachment?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Does anyone know of any customisations or add-ons that will allow you to send a document from a document library as an email attachment, rather than merely be able to SEND TO, E-MAIL A LINK.

This is for SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 3):

https://sendemailsp2010.codeplex.com - solution to send doc in attachments. currently is not for SPOnline. But it's not using serverside code - all logic in JS, thus I believe it can be converted to SPOnline.

Comment: I believe using java script on client side is not best approach to send e-mail with attachment. For SharePoint Online I see two approaches: Workflow or Web Service

Answer (score 3):

You can create list level workflow and use workflow action to send e-mail. Have a look at third-party workflow action called "[Workflow Activity Pack for SharePoint Online](http://plumsail.com/workflow-activity-pack/)".

It has workflow action "[Send email with attachments](http://plumsail.com/workflow-activity-pack/docs/activities-description/#SendEmail)". This is a paid product, but I think this may be what you need.

You can find example and details in [this blog post.](http://plumsail.blogspot.ru/2013/12/how-to-create-helpdesk-on-sharepoint.html)

P.S.: I'm member of developers team of this product and I like to implement new features =)

Comment: Please add more details to your answer, if the link breaks it will be of little help to future readers as it's written now.

Comment: I think you also need to add information regarding your association with this product

Comment: Of course, fixed.